# ui-router, how to resolve a local result, then a remote result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have this feeling it's not possible to do what I want with just plain resolves,.

Basically, I need a way of having a property resolve in a ui-router route then update that property at a later time or have it resolve twice.

So say for example, you have a posts page, it'll load the posts from the cache, show the page, then send off a request to a remote server(which may or may not succeed) and update the resolved property with the new information.

Anyone know the best way to handle this?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but I would guess if you could do it, you would have to mess around with the templateCache  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache then update the cache on the callback.

Comment: Not sure what's impossible about this, I mean you laid out exactly what you would need to do in pretty clear steps and this is a perfect spot for a directive. ui-router would load the data initially and that data would be injected into a controller. The HTML template for that controller would then ng-repeat a directive for each item in the data. The directive would handle, once instantiated (or once explicitly called by the user), going out and getting updated data for specifically that item. Unless I'm not understanding you correctly, that's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a  basic sample of a solution that uses custom localStorage and a dataService that serves as your DAL. You can tell it to use cachedData or get "fresh data" (where you would go out to your API), then serve that data back to your controller for rendering. This is the bare bones implementation of it and isn't meant to be a full solution for you but meant to get you on the right track for what you want to do.

```js
angular.module('app.factories', [])
  .factory('localStorage', function() {
    var dummyData = [{
      'id': 1,
      'someProperty': 1,
      'someOtherProperty': 2
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'someProperty': 3,
      'someOtherProperty': 4
    }];

    return {
      supported: function() {
        return true; // SO restriction won't let me use localStorage, fair enough, just mock it
        //return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
      },
      get: function(key) {
        return dummyData;
        //return localStorage[key];
      },
      set: function(key, value) {
        //localStorage[key] = value;
      }
    }
  })
  .factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorage',
    function($http, $q, local) {
      return {
        get: function(useCached) {
          var cachedData = local.supported() && useCached ? local.get('data') : undefined;

          var dummyData = [{
            'id': 1,
            'someProperty': 1,
            'someOtherProperty': 2
          }, {
            'id': 2,
            'someProperty': 3,
            'someOtherProperty': 4
          }];

          var deferred = $q.defer(),
            promise = deferred.promise;

          if (cachedData) {
            console.log('using cachedData in get()');
            deferred.resolve(cachedData);
          } else {
            console.log('getting fresh data in get()');
            local.set('data', dummyData);
            deferred.resolve(dummyData);
          }

          return promise;
        },
        getById: function(id, useCached) {
          var cachedData = local.supported() && useCached ? local.get('data' + id) : undefined;

          var dummyForId1 = {
              'id': 1,
              'someProperty': 5,
              'someOtherProperty': 6
            },
            dummyForId2 = {
              'id': 2,
              'someProperty': 7,
              'someOtherProperty': 8
            };

          var deferred = $q.defer(),
            promise = deferred.promise;

          if (cachedData) {
            console.log('using cachedData in getById()');
            deferred.resolve(cachedData);
          } else {
            console.log('getting fresh data in getById(' + id + ')');
            if (id === 1) {
              local.set('data1', dummyForId1);
              deferred.resolve(dummyForId1);
            } else if (id === 2) {
              local.set('data2', dummyForId2);
              deferred.resolve(dummyForId2);
            }
          }

          return promise;
        }
      }
    }
  ]);

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.factories'])
  .config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        template: '<span>This is the home page</span><br /><div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.someProperty}}, {{item.someOtherProperty}} <button ng-click="refreshMe(item)">Refresh Me!</button></div>',
        resolve: {
          data: ['dataService',
            function(dataService) {
              return dataService.get(true).then(function(response) {
                return response;
              });
            }
          ]
        }
      });
    }
  ])
  .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', 'data',
    function($scope, dataService, data) {
      console.log('in homeCtrl');
      $scope.data = data;

      $scope.refreshMe = function(item) {
        console.log(item)
        dataService.getById(item.id).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          item.someProperty = response.someProperty;
          item.someOtherProperty = response.someOtherProperty;
        });
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <dib ng-view>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept - `$timeout()` as promise service to simulate that content can change and will change in future. Initial text is **first content** and it will be changed after 2 seconds to **second content**

```js
angular
.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/content', {
        template: ['<div>', '<p>content: {{ ctrl.text.content }}</p>', '</div>'].join(''),
        controller: 'controller',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        resolve: {
            content: function(contentFactory) {
                return contentFactory.getText();   
            }
        }
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/content'
    });
})
.service('contentFactory', function($timeout) {
    this.text = {
        content: 'first content'
    }
    
    this.getText = function() {
      return this.text;   
    }
    
    $timeout(function() {
        this.text.content = 'second content'
    }.bind(this), 2000);
})
.controller('controller', function(content) {
    this.text = content;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>$timeout()</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```